# How to change default search in browser Opera through search.ini and operaprefs.ini

Tags: search, opera

If I just change parameters in search.ini - new search will be added but it will not be set as default.

I found out that there is a paremeter in operaprefs.ini in [State] section - 
Data2=02827edd9d4c131d98daea963133db3d757

If numbers rught, then all works perfectly!

How to genereate that numbers correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt that it can be changed through just editing those configuration files. Data2 is uniquely generated hash. Moreover, default search is maintained by search.ini with key `Default Search` and value is MD5 hash of `[Search Engine *]`. So, the process can't be automated, one have to manually Add & Set default search engine. Sadly, Opera is not open-source.

Comment: Why not just set it from Opera's UI? ;-)

Comment: :) Yes I can do it on my PC, but I need to change it while installing other product on user's PC...